# Get name of constraint which caused SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I get the name of the constraint which caused the SQLiteConstraintException.

Calling toString() on the exception just gives me: "error code 19: constraint failed"

And there is no method in the exception to get the cause. This makes it rather difficult to debug my sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with version [3.7.17](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_17.html), SQLite shows the name of the constraint in error messages:

```
sqlite> create table t(x, constraint x_positive check (x>0));
sqlite> insert into t values(-1);
Error: constraint x_positive failed
```

However, it will be some time before this version shows up in Android.

In the meantime, you could replace the constraint with a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that can use whatever message it likes:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_x_positive
BEFORE INSERT ON t                -- also UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.x <= 0
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'RED ALERT! database on fire because x <= 0');
END;
```